# Handle Button in CCNode from CCScene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccnode, ccscene

I'm creating a game in cocos2d v3. In the `CCScene`, I add a `CCNode` that contains all the components for my HUD. In the CCNode, there are `CCButton`s added. I want to be able to handle the touch of these buttons in my `CCScene`. Is that possible? And if so, how is it done elegantly?

Code that I tested this morning and is working:

`CCNode` header file (Header class):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCButton *goldButton;
```

I set up the basics of the gold button in the implementation file of the CCNode (positioning, sprite frame, etc).

`CCScene` implementation file (PlayScene class):

```
-(void) setup {
    _header = [[Header alloc] init];
    [_header.goldButton setTarget:self selector:@selector(goldButtonTapped)];
}
```

Seems a little weird setting the target of the button inside the scene, but it works. I am wondering of the 'best practice', if you will, for this situation.

Comment: post your code how you've (tried to) set it up. Are you using spritebuilder?

Comment: Code added to question. It works but seems convoluded in my opinion. Not using spritebuilder.